# Add month to a variable date in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a date being passed into a shell script and have to add a month to that.
for eg:

```
passed_date=2017-06-01
```

i need to add 1 month to it :

```
converted_date=2017-07-01
```

How can i achieve this in a shell script.
I tried converting date to seconds since epoch and then adding 1 month like:

```
date +%s -d 20170601 -d "+1 month"
```

and then converting seconds back to yyyy-mm-dd by

```
date -d@$(date +%s -d 20170601 -d "+1 month") +%Y-%m-%d
```

but its basically adding 1 month to current system date

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to be looking for:

```
date -d "20170601+1 month" +%Y-%m-%d
```

When using multiple `-d` flags in the same command, `date` seems to only use the last one.

And of course, feel free to replace `20170601` by `$VAR` containing any date.

Comment: It is important remember to make this calculate,the date want to be complete formatted with day, month and year.

Comment: An addendum to this answer: `date -d "20170601 + 1 month - 1 day" +%Y-%m-%d` shows the first and last days of the month.

Comment: It seems if you don't specify a date for adding 1 month, it takes the current date.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS High Sierra

```
date -v+1m -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2017-06-01"
```

Comment: I think the input format (`-f`) should probably read `%Y-%m-%d` (lowercase `m`) instead.